# Response.WriteFile -- Write out a byte stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is is possible to write to the http response stream from a dynamically created bitmap using the Response.Write/WriteFile without saving the image to the hard drive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and assign it to [`Response.OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx), or simply use `Response.OutputStream` directly when saving the bitmap.

There is an example in the documentation on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) page, though it simply saves the bitmap directly to the output stream:

```
// Set the correct content type, so browser/client knows what you are sending
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.Clear();

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have your bitmap stored in a `byte[]` you can also dump that directly into `Response.BinaryWrite(myByteArray);`, as long as you have your content-type, length and disposition set correctly (as mentioned by @arx).

Answer (score 2):

How about [Response.BinaryWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524318(VS.90).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Make sure you set the content-type correctly and it should work fine.